# Google copyright information not showing in GMSMapView in iPhone but shows in iPad

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview, copyright-display

I am trying to submit an app to the App Store but it got rejected because the iPhone view of the Map doesn't have the necessary copyright information. I checked the code which is in Objective-C and couldn't find anything that hides the Copy Right information. I installed the same app in iPad and I could see the Copy Right Logo at the bottom right of the screen. My intuition is that for some reason the iPhone map is not showing the entire map due to space constraint and somehow losing the copyright logo along the way.

I try changing the camera position, zoom level, etc but none of them seems to work. I also removed all the constraint and that didn't help either. I also put the exact code Google has given as an example and even in that the Google logo is not showing on either bottom right or left part of the app.

Here is the snippet of the viewDidLoad method that is putting the map view

```
 GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView new];

    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    self.view = mapView;

    [self.mapView setCamera:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:[LocationManager currentLocation] zoom:9.0]];

    [self resetMarkersWithNotification:YES];
```

This is how it looks on iPhone as you can see there is no Google Copyright information anywhere in the app [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiP7G.png)
Here how the same code look inside the iPad [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5jlz.jpg)

Comment: You need to call [GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo] as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro#attribution_requirements

Comment: thanks @evan. Will try it out.

Comment: Great! Please let me know if this fixes the copyright issue.

Comment: it did. Thank you very much.

Comment: Heya thanks for your update, glad to hear it helped, will post this as my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]` as stated in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro#attribution_requirements):

> Attribution Requirements
>
> If you use the Maps SDK for iOS in your
>   application, you must include the attribution text as part of a legal
>   notices section in your application. Including legal notices as an
>   independent menu item, or as part of an "About" menu item, is
>   recommended.
>
> You can get the attribution text by making a call to `[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]`.